# How to make a font bolder through CSS?

Tags: css

How to make a font bolder through CSS and why the `font-weight: bold` property doesn't work for the top menu here: https://tiarstudio.ro/index.php ?

Comment: Your web font needs to support multiple weights...

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
font-weight:value;
```

where value can be from 100,200,300 to 900

or you can use

```
font-weight:lighter, bold, bolder;
```

Answer (score 1):

As @evolutionxbox mentioned in the comments your font needs to support multiple weights in order for the font weights mentioned in [Raj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44606411/8157693) to work.

I see the following in your page

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One:regular&amp;subset=latin" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Now if you open that CSS file - by directly visiting the link - you will see the following in its contents:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Julius Sans One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Julius Sans One'), local('JuliusSansOne-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/juliussansone/v5/iU65JP9acQHPDLkdalCF7qW9WqC4OJJkfgA_jCJuPCQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
```

Notice how it says `font-weight: 400;`

This tells you that that particular font doesn't not support bold and that's why it desn't work in your case.

As for the other font

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface:regular&amp;subset=latin" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Below are the contests for the other font's CSS sheet. The same also applies, the font doesn't support bold

```
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Abril Fatface';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Abril Fatface'), local('AbrilFatface-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abrilfatface/v8/X1g_KwGeBV3ajZIXQ9VnDn1PgMwFt2V-WJ2uOZ4WXLU.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Abril Fatface';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Abril Fatface'), local('AbrilFatface-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abrilfatface/v8/X1g_KwGeBV3ajZIXQ9VnDjxObtw73-qQgbr7Be51v5c.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
```

---

**Bonus**

With that being said, I wonder...if you copy the contents of the google font CSS sheet - then add them to the main Stylesheet - and then modify the font-wight lines to include more wights...would that make any difference? I leave it to experts to answer.

```css
/* Start Julius Sans One */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Julius Sans One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900;
  src: local('Julius Sans One'), local('JuliusSansOne-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/juliussansone/v5/iU65JP9acQHPDLkdalCF7qW9WqC4OJJkfgA_jCJuPCQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
} 
/* End Julius Sans One */

/* Start Abril Fatface */
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Abril Fatface';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900;
  src: local('Abril Fatface'), local('AbrilFatface-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abrilfatface/v8/X1g_KwGeBV3ajZIXQ9VnDn1PgMwFt2V-WJ2uOZ4WXLU.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Abril Fatface';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900;
  src: local('Abril Fatface'), local('AbrilFatface-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abrilfatface/v8/X1g_KwGeBV3ajZIXQ9VnDjxObtw73-qQgbr7Be51v5c.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
/* End Abril Fatface */

/* Start Font-family Settings */
.Julius-font {font-family: "Julius Sans One"}
.Abril-font {font-family: "Abril Fatface"}
/* End Font-family Settings */


/* Start Font-weight Settings */
.f-100 {font-weight: 100}
.f-200 {font-weight: 200}
.f-300 {font-weight: 300}
.f-400 {font-weight: 400}
.f-500 {font-weight: 500}
.f-600 {font-weight: 600}
.f-700 {font-weight: 700}
.f-800 {font-weight: 800}
.f-900 {font-weight: 900}
/* End Font-weight Settings */
```

```html
<h1>Abril-font</h1>
<p class="Abril-font f-100">Test 100</p>
<p class="Abril-font f-200">Test 200</p>
<p class="Abril-font f-300">Test 300</p>
<p class="Abril-font f-400">Test 400</p>
<p class="Abril-font f-500">Test 500</p>
<p class="Abril-font f-600">Test 600</p>
<p class="Abril-font f-700">Test 700</p>
<p class="Abril-font f-800">Test 800</p>
<p class="Abril-font f-900">Test 900</p>

<h1>Julius-font</h1>
<p class="Julius-font f-100">Test 100</p>
<p class="Julius-font f-200">Test 200</p>
<p class="Julius-font f-300">Test 300</p>
<p class="Julius-font f-400">Test 400</p>
<p class="Julius-font f-500">Test 500</p>
<p class="Julius-font f-600">Test 600</p>
<p class="Julius-font f-700">Test 700</p>
<p class="Julius-font f-800">Test 800</p>
<p class="Julius-font f-900">Test 900</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's what I have suspected, but you provided the proof - the font doesn't support having its weight property modified. I also tried to overwrite its settings by adding the contents of the google font CSS sheets to my main CSS file through the custom css field. This is the best answer so far but will still wait for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a CSS style applied to it:

```
.xprt_mega_menu ul.sf-menu > li > a {
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

So it's already bold.  I tried 900 (max) instead of bold (700), and there was no discernible change.

Answer (score 0):

```
font-weight: bold;
```

This will work in any website. I opened your website and the text in the menu at the top was already bold. There were even two CSS rules that were responsible for that - .xprt_mega_menu ul.sf-menu > li > a{font-weight: bold } and .xprt_mega_menu ul.sf-menu > li > a{ font-weight: 700}.

Otherwise you can use a value like: font-weight: 100 - 900; However, not all fonts support all of these values. usually font-weight: 700 is used to make a text bold via this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `font-weight` property. It can contain the following values: `100-900`, `normal`, `bold`, `bolder` and `lighter`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_font_weight.asp).

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<span class="bold">I'm a bold text!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
font-weight: value;
```

Values are:

```
font-weight: bold;
font-weight: bolder;
font-weight: light;
```

Or use: 100-900

Don't forget the semicolons!!